# Just installed Windows 10 and Eclipse no more starts

Tags: android, eclipse, 64-bit, windows-10

I just upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 10 (both 64-bit) and my previous Eclipse Juno with ADT-plugin for Android development is no longer starting.

All I can see is the mouse pointer showing that something is loading for a few seconds and then nothing else happens.

**What I tried**

- renamed `eclipse.ini` to let it recreate it: did not even recreate it, so renamed it back.
- turned on "Windows 8" compatibility on Eclipse exe. No changes.
- tried to look at `workspaceDir/.metadata/.log`. No entries about this.

What follows are the contents of `eclipse.ini`:

```
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
    -product
    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256m
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    -Xms512m
    -Xmx1024m
```

And this is the Java version I have installed:

```
    C:\Users\user>java -version
    java version "1.8.0_51"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
    Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

I'm stuck. Where can I find more clues since I've still not found others experiencing the same issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved.

Just uninstalled completely Java and JDK (also manually deleted "Java" folder in "C:\ProgramFiles") and downloaded and reinstalled the very same version of JDK Windows x64 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), and everything works again now.

Comment: To avoid conflicts or system updates interfering in the future, you should specify the path to the JVM you want Eclipse to use via `eclipse.ini`, as specified in https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by first reinstalling java, then removing PATH variable "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" and 
resetting the PATH variable for JDK.
steps for setting path variable:

1. go to control panel
2. double click "system"
3. click on "Advanced system setting"
4. click on "environment variable"
5. select "path" and click on "edit"
6. remove "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath"
7. reset JDK path as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin" and "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\lib\tools.jar"
8. click ok
9. restart eclipse.
   resolved. Here my PC java version is 1.8.0_65. Your may be different. But set path as your JDK version.

Answer (score 2):

I was also having the same problem.I just checked my java version as stated above it was showing 1.8.0 so I just removed the "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;"
form the system variable and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem but i didn't uninstall java, i just set the java variable in system settings and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall java. Just remove the following line from your environment(system) variables, which will be in starting of path variable. Windows 10 is keeping a copy of all your program files in ProgramData folder location .To confirm, Check the java version from your command line before and after change.  It worked for me...

"C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;"

Answer (score 0):

I had my Java path set correctly in **eclipse.ini** but forgot to check "bitness" of eclipse and JVM. These have to pair (32 bit or 64 both) otherwise eclipse fails to start without error or message.

It is a foolish error but not so obvious when upgrading, so maybe this saves someone else few minutes or more...

Answer (score 0):

```
Retain single version of java and uninstall all other versions
and update the eclipse.ini text file as below but change the java path and versions appropriately.




-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 0):

in the eclipse.ini file just add this line:

--add-modules=java.se.ee

after the
--vmargs 
line