# eclipse.exe stop working in windows 10

Tags: eclipse, upgrade, windows-10

I recently update my Windows7 to Windows10 by free Microsoft reservation and upgradation.
Before upgradation eclipse started normally and didn't has any problem but since I upgrade my windows I can't run it , when I try to open it I get the "eclipse.exe stop working" error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729714/just-installed-windows-10-and-eclipse-no-more-starts

Comment: @pbwned but i doen't work for me...
I didn't change anything....
I just try to open eclipse

Comment: Try the solution that pbwned pointed out. For me was a problem related to Java installation indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too got the same error. I tried following steps.

Reinstalled JDK (JDK 1.8 update 60 - 64 bit)
Installed fresh copy of eclipse (latest version - Eclipse 4.5 Mars)
Installed 32 bit version of JDK

None of these worked for me.

Finally I opened the eclipse by right clicking and Run As Administrator option - found this option in another forum. This worked for me.

Comment: Is there any solution without running eclipse with administrator privilege?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open eclipse via the commandline. (Open cmd, go to the eclipse folder, run eclipse.exe). You might get more information about the crash there and we can try to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also  facing this issue between Windows 10 and Eclipse Luna 4.4.2.
It was working just fine for several weeks and one day it begins.
I try to upgrade my JDK to 1.8.66 without success; try older JDK 1.7.80 and same problem.

I was able to run eclipse after adding JAVA_HOME environment variable and launching eclipse ide as administrator, as @Shyamkumar suggested above.

Another really ANNOYING thing is how the moderators of StackOverflow  evaluate some questions posted here. Please Do Not downgrade questions if the answers may help other people. It is not about you, but the others !

Comment: By the way, I forgot to mention  I switch both JRE and Eclipse to 32bits version. This configuration works just fine.

Comment: Downvotes are provided by the community and usually they are attached to bad-posed or bad-formatted questions. They aim to be an esortation to apply more effort on their clarity in order to become even more useful and accessible.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse.ini file at VM, if it looks like:

```
-vm C:/Users/Nitin/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932/jre/bin
```

try replacing it with the following:

```
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\javaw.exe
```

**Note:** The folder depends on the JDK version you have installed.
Try this. It worked for me.