# Just upgraded to Windows 10 and Eclipse mars no more starts

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-10, eclipse-mars

I just upgraded to windows 10 and eclipse mars no more starts.
However my older eclipse v3.7.0 works all fine.

I followed the answers under this link:
[Just installed Windows 10 and Eclipse no more starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729714/just-installed-windows-10-and-eclipse-no-more-starts)

However it seems that I might have messed up something else too. Maybe deleted some files or dirs I am not able to figure out.

When I start eclipse I get this stack trace:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing storage.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:295)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleDatabase$Persistence.readWire(ModuleDatabase.java:1168)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleDatabase$Persistence.load(ModuleDatabase.java:1028)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleDatabase.load(ModuleDatabase.java:879)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.<init>(Storage.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.createStorage(Storage.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:75)
        ... 10 more
```

Please let me know what might be going wrong.

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: The only thing that can be guessed from that error is that some file that Eclipse is trying to read is broken or from an older version of Eclipse perhaps. I'd actually detail the steps you did that led up to your predicament.